# How to extract some unit tests to separate gradle test task?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle

Let's say I want to separate Robolectric tests from normal unit tests and run them as separate gradle task. Is it possible?

I've managed to exclude unwanted tests from unit tests:

```
android {
    ...

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            exclude 'package/with/robolectric/tests/**'
        }
    }
}
```

but now I'm unsure how to configure separate test task which will include only tests from `package/with/robolectric/tests/` package.

I found similar problem but the answer is not working:
[Separate integration test task on gradle with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604917/separate-integration-test-task-on-gradle-with-android)

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
testOptions {
    if (!project.hasProperty("INTEGRATIONTESTS")) {
        unitTests.all {
            exclude 'package/with/robolectric/tests/**'
        }
    }
}
```

and run Gradle with `-PINTEGRATIONTESTS=true`